# What is the difference between ignition temperature and flash point?

Tags: combustion

I am trying to clarify this for Class 8 Science. Their textbook says "It is the lowest temperature at which a substance catches fire". However, it does not clarify whether it is on its own or due to an external source. I read through various websites and there are both kinds of definitions put up! Some also mentioned a flash point. So wanted to know what the proper definition of ignition temperature is and how it differs from flash point. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

From Wikipedia:

[Autoignition Temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoignition_temperature): the lowest temperature at which a substance **spontaneously** ignites **without** a source of ignition (such as a flame or spark).

[Flash Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_point): the lowest temperature at which the **vapours** of a (volatile) material will ignite, **with** an ignition source.

[Ignition temperature](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ignition%20temperature) means the same thing as autoignition temperature according to Merriam Webster.

Comment: The question talks about "ignition temperature", not "**auto**ignition temperature". To be a reasonable answer to the question, you would have to demonstrate that "ignition temperature" is almost certainly a mis-reading of "autoignition temperature." (i.e. that "ignition temperature" isn't a thing distinct from "autoignition temperature".)

Comment: @R.M. The resolution might be the frequent use of overly casual language. Many people might causally say "ignition temperature" when they mean *auto*ignition temperature.

Comment: I always heard the two used interchangeably, and figured the second one was shortened for ease of speech.