# Is there any difference between "autoignition temperature" and "ignition temperature"?

Tags: energy, heat, temperature

Is there any difference between the "autoignition temperature" and the "ignition temperature" of a substance?

Comment: Sure. Autoignition temperature is the temperature at which the substance catches fire, and ignition temperature is not a thing at all. Then again, there is a thing called flash point: it is a temperature above which the substance will burn _if ignited_.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/82810/what-is-the-difference-between-ignition-temperature-and-flash-point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autoignition temperature is the lowest temperature at which a substance can spontaneously ignite in a normal atmosphere without an external source (spark,flame etc).

"Ignition temperature" is what people call autoignition temperature who don't care about details. As Ivan said, there is no such thing as ignition temperature.